# Positioning a fake mirror for best effect

Tags: code-golf, matrix

## Challenge

### Premise

Consider a mosaic of \$m\times n\$ tiles, in \$k\$ unique colours designated by integers. Example (\$3\times6\$, four colours):

```
4 1 3 2 4 2
1 2 4 2 1 3
4 3 2 1 4 4
```

My poor man's mirror is a pane of glass of width \$\sqrt{2}\cdot\min(m,n)\$. I stand it diagonally on the mosaic, like so:

```
4 1 3 M 4 2
1 2 M 2 1 3
4 M 2 1 4 4
```

For this example I can pretend it reflects exactly two full tiles:

```
x 1 x M x x
x 2 M x x x
x M 2 1 x x
```

No matter what diagonal I choose, this is the **greatest number** of full tiles I can fake-reflect. Yay.

### Task

Input: an integer matrix of \$m\$ rows and \$n\$ columns where \$2\leq m\leq1000,2\leq n\leq1000\$. The number of unique values is \$k\$ where \$3\leq k\ll mn\$.

Output: three integers, in any format. The first and second respectively represent the row coordinate and column coordinate of the matrix element ('mosaic tile') at the **left** end of the 45-degree diagonal where the fake mirror should be placed for 'best effect', effectiveness being defined as shown above. The third integer is 0 or 1, respectively meaning a rising (bottom left to top right) or falling (top left to bottom right) diagonal.

For clarity's sake, here are some simple test cases.

#### Example 1

Input:

```
4 1 3 2 4 2
1 2 4 2 1 3
4 3 2 1 4 4
```

Output: `3 2 0`

#### Example 2

Input:

```
3 6
4 7
5 8
1 2
2 1
```

Output: `4 1 1` or `5 1 0` (not both)

As you can see, **a unique solution isn't guaranteed**.

#### Example 3

Input:

```
2  7  4  10 7  8  9  5  6  4  2  4  10 2  1  7  10 7  2  4  10 10 8  7
6  5  6  2  2  3  6  1  6  9  7  2  10 3  4  7  8  8  3  7  1  8  4  2
3  3  7  6  10 1  7  9  10 10 2  6  4  7  5  6  9  1  1  5  7  6  2  7
7  10 3  9  8  10 9  3  6  1  6  10 3  8  9  6  3  6  2  10 1  2  8  1
7  7  8  1  1  6  4  8  10 3  10 4  9  3  1  9  5  9  10 4  6  7  10 4
1  10 9  7  7  10 3  3  7  8  2  2  4  2  4  7  1  7  7  1  9  9  8  7
5  9  5  3  8  6  5  7  6  7  2  7  9  9  7  10 8  8  7  3  5  9  9  10
9  3  8  2  9  2  1  3  6  3  8  5  7  10 10 9  1  1  10 2  5  1  6  9
8  7  6  2  3  2  9  9  9  7  9  5  8  3  8  2  2  5  2  2  10 10 3  5
7  1  1  2  3  2  10 1  2  10 3  3  2  1  4  2  5  6  10 9  6  5  3  8
8  9  5  2  1  4  10 6  8  6  9  10 10 8  1  6  10 6  4  8  7  9  3  5
8  1  5  7  1  8  7  5  8  6  4  5  10 1  6  1  4  4  10 7  6  3  3  6
```

Output: `1 10 1`

### Edit - indexing

The example outputs are 1-indexed, but **0-indexing is allowed**.

## Remarks

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins.
- [Standard rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/), [I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) and [loophole rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- If possible, link an online demo of your code.
- Please explain your code.

Comment: Also, how would [this configuration](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/a@v9b9CoULBWAFE@nKBSBMQS6ECyDZUMAWxwGwjIMsUKGfMBZI1AsoBxf9r6f8HAA) be scored? Is it \$3\$ (the longest reflected ray) or \$5\$ (the sum of all reflected rays)?

Comment: @Arnauld 5. As stated in the post, we're only _counting_ reflected elements.

Comment: Can the mirror leave the mosaic or must it be placed such that it fits (e.g. in the 3x6 example are `2 1 0` and `2 4 1` placements to be considered or not)?

Comment: It has to fit; there's a reason why I talked about 45 degrees and \$\sqrt{2}\cdot\min(m,n)\$.

Comment: Can you add another larger test case, maybe something whose min side is 10-15?

Comment: @Jonah Done. Remember, the example outputs are 1-indexed.

Comment: Thanks.  I have it working but the output format makes it almost 2 challenges.  A more natural format would be `(<index in the larger of the two axes>, <rising or falling>)` -- I don't suppose that's acceptable?

Comment: I admit that sounds nice, but the one answer already made as at the time of adding this comment isn't like that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 91 bytes

```
≔⟦⟧θＷＳ⊞θＩ⪪ι ≔Ｌ§θ⁰η≔⊖⌊⟦Ｌθη⟧ζＦ⁻ＬθζＦ⁻ηζＦ²⊞υ⟦Σ⭆⊕ζ⭆⊕ζ⁼§§θ⁺ι⎇λμ⁻ζμ⁺κξ§§θ⁺ι⎇λξ⁻ζξ⁺κμ⎇λι⁺ιζκλ⟧Ｉ✂⌈υ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVE9b4QwDN35FdZNjpRKhbJ1OvU6nFQkJLohhohLj6ghx0fSUv48dQAVOlTqlPj5@dnPLivRlTehp@nY9@pqMC84tOwx@KyUloBn0zib2U6ZKzIGqesrbDk8id5i1mhlUXE4wIExqlklXqS52gqP9mwucvD0e8Y4VBvjJMtO1tJYecFEGVW7GvO1rPXUwheMVPB268BTXI@7/Eij7DLVDonWIR2HPCPZZfZENGRlazqSyN@Z59YJ3f8Y2BlJNbUjx6@yM6L7Qs2h5rBMMdKf1sBW1juHwQf/Uxl2KsNvlVnUAzu62kRGnyKaLmhdKVmyuFxHq1JiIoZ5u45IoT/SNMUQwgNEEEMUhMvrkSCe0ZDiOJjuPvQ3) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Explanation:

```
≔⟦⟧θＷＳ⊞θＩ⪪ι
```

Input the mosaic. (These 12 bytes could be avoided by requiring the input to be in JSON format, but I was too lazy to punctuate the example.)

```
≔Ｌ§θ⁰η
```

Get the width of the mosaic.

```
≔⊖⌊⟦Ｌθη⟧ζ
```

Get the inner size of the mirror, i.e. the distance from the first to the last character of the mirror in terms of diagonal steps.

```
Ｆ⁻Ｌθζ
```

Loop over the possible row(s) of the top left corner of the mirror's enclosing square.

```
Ｆ⁻ηζ
```

Loop over the possible column(s) of the top left corner of the mirror's square.

```
Ｆ²
```

Loop over the possible rotations of the mirror.

```
⊞υ⟦Σ⭆⊕ζ⭆⊕ζ⁼§§θ⁺ι⎇λμ⁻ζμ⁺κξ§§θ⁺ι⎇λξ⁻ζξ⁺κμ⎇λι⁺ιζκλ⟧
```

Calculate the number of tiles it reflects exactly. Exact matches are counted twice and the diagonal is also counted but this doesn't affect the relative score. Push this number along with the potential solution to the predefined empty list.

```
Ｉ✂⌈υ¹
```

Output the solution with the highest number of exactly reflected tiles.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 557 bytes:

```py
E=enumerate
V=lambda x,y,n,m:0<=x<n and 0<=y<m
U=lambda j,k,J,K,b,n,m:b[j][k]==b[J][K]if V(j,k,n,m)and V(J,K,n,m)else 0
def f(b):
 n,m=len(b),len(b[0])
 q,r=[i for x,u in E(b)for y,_ in E(u)for i in[(x,y,0,0,x,y)]*(x+1>=min(n,m)and y+min(n,m)<=m)+[(x,y,1,0,x,y)]*(x+1>=min(n,m)and y+1>=min(n,m))],[]
 while q:
  x,y,d,c,X,Y=q.pop(0)
  if abs(X-x)+1==min(n,m):r+=[(*[[x,y],[X,Y]][d],d,c)];continue
  q+=[(x,y,d,c+U(*[[X+1,Y+1,X-1,Y-1],[X+1,Y-1,X-1,Y+1]][d],b,n,m)+U(*[[X,Y+1,X-1,Y],[X,Y-1,X+1,Y]][d],b,n,m),X-1,Y+[1,-1][d])]
 return max(r,key=lambda x:x[-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRNb6MwED2vf8Wol5riVhgIH9mwt1660t5apfKiijREpQ0kIUSb/Prs2GbcrFStQsCeee/N@NmwPQ1vmy7Ktv35fF/U3aGt@2qo2VOxrtrFsoKjOIlOtNNgVhxnHVTdEnB4mrXskSDv4kM8iJ9iYYAL9V6qj7IoFuqhVD/LZgVPXEMw6Wn6E9dgPavX@xoCtqxXsOILb8oAo8W67nAizEMFpcdgJ/pCNbDa9NjOAZoO7hGhpyfxYqcHM21worhuOcAfPr3yhh99@aNom45TAyefZrOi9XxLkP8lXAS8UqiSwZ@3Zl3DDns2Fi3Fq5iL52J3t91seYBNAy68Wuz5/Pbo@bJw/GnvF4rfKIU0lEJSWaplqRW88vvrphua7lAjf6dxo7b/qBlzX4pn/M9v8XkrNds3IxvxpVUy@@CNlE@CLabBmnQJHelKChTFsIfr6@vh0HfQVkfei4/65M7D9KgQ5Z33sri6umIxSIgghBhCJu1TRzAemVEMMdO4fWjgESSYStkEMg1nCLHpyKRDgBSQAzLQgwwgB5gAJCYYUgoH0iAtzMXxQkrKEiKF5orMWJp7DiMDsZHh2TqZgaUGltlq2OwYS6y6GedUKaS2UqqWG7Y005TqpyylYrmRxnH@b082axebUCqkmqFlaRnbqiReTHqRuccwCkuyLad4Qm7FTFIHKcXcMjMyzHmdktEpqdo16A0ca9jOk4tFW39Tgtsi1uLU4CeUkgHLSSE0EbuzEfmQkay13Bls7Z@4TWXZheMRibn6ttPsopRlh85m48KEpVTAybg9cEbZFmPSSMjPxNnB3Ll1WIQkZFR@cVbdAXDbmdIuTlh2cZgkJSckE1sDAtIwEffqWP@0keb90t/YYfOy2FT9ku/xU/ttfMGVummrLW@6QTR3@@26GTh@4uhjCqtmPdQ9/7XpagH7EXD9u7tGEGPbHnl8xT@Vped5X4TDr8MRhs9/AQ)